# How to check the number of confirmations for a transaction?

Tags: transaction-confirmation

I assume XMR should have confirmations similar to BTC, so how to check it? I am asking because when I transfer monero to poloniex using monero-wallet-cli, poloniex kept me waiting for a while. When it was Bitcoin, I usually check the confirmations to know how long it will be, but in monero, how can I check it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no "amount of confirmations" displayed by any of the block explorers. However, an easy way around this is to subtract the block your transaction was included in from the current blockheight. This will give you the number of confirmations. Thus, let's say your transaction was included into block 1111111 and the current blockheight is 1111130, your transaction has `1111130 - 1111111 = 29` confirmations.

Note that you can check the blockheight of your transaction by entering the transaction ID / hash into [MoneroBlocks](http://moneroblocks.info). The `From Block` is the blockheight your transaction was included in. The `Height` on the front page of [MoneroBlocks](http://moneroblocks.info) is the current blockheight.

Answer (score 2):

You can lookup the transaction in the daemon by its txid:

`print_tx TXID`

This will show the transaction data, as well as where it was found: in the blockchain (along with the block height it was mined in), or in the pool.

The `status` command tells you the current blockchain height.